# Usage of BaseConsumerRecord (Deprecated) in MirrorMakerMessageHandler?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a newer or recommended way of writing MirrorMakerMessageHandler since BaseConsumerRecord is marked as Deprecated?

```
public class CustomHandler implements kafka.tools.MirrorMaker.MirrorMakerMessageHandler {

    @Override
    public java.util.List<org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]>> handle(kafka.consumer.BaseConsumerRecord arg0) {

        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are [implementing an interface](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/MirrorMaker.scala#L567-L572) so there is no workaround until the API changes, or a new way to mirror topics is written [(KIP-382)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0)